# How to count only the first sequence of same results in AWS Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I'm trying to to to create a consistency score for an ID for a specific date based on the next 6 days(current date included), so in total, a 7 day window.
And I want to count only the first sequence of same results as the result in the first date.

Lets say I have this data:

| **Date "dd/mm/yyyy"** | **ID** | **Result** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/03/2021 | 1 | true |
| 02/03/2021 | 1 | true |
| 03/03/2021 | 1 | true |
| 04/03/2021 | 1 | false |
| 05/03/2021 | 1 | false |
| 06/03/2021 | 1 | true |
| 07/03/2021 | 1 | false |
| 08/03/2021 | 1 | false |
| 09/03/2021 | 1 | false |
| 10/03/2021 | 1 | false |
| 11/03/2021 | 1 | false |
| 12/03/2021 | 1 | false |
| 13/03/2021 | 1 | false |
| 14/03/2021 | 1 | false |

Expected results:

| **Date** | **ID** | **Score** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/03/2021 | 1 | 3 |
| 02/03/2021 | 1 | 2 |
| 03/03/2021 | 1 | 1 |
| 04/03/2021 | 1 | 2 |
| 05/03/2021 | 1 | 1 |
| 06/03/2021 | 1 | 1 |
| 07/03/2021 | 1 | 7 |

I hope my explanation is adequate.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions for this.  I think this does what you want:

```
select (case when result = 'true'
             then coalesce(date_diff(day,
                                     date
                                     min(case when result = 'false' then date end) over
                                          (partition by id
                                           order by date
                                           rows between current row and 6 following
                                          )
                                         ),
                            count(*) over (partition by id order by date rows between current row and 6 following)
                           )
             else coalesce(date_diff(day,
                                     date
                                     min(case when result = 'true' then date end) over
                                          (partition by id
                                           order by date
                                           rows between current row and 6 following
                                          )
                                         ),
                            count(*) over (partition by id order by date rows between current row and 6 following)
                           )
        end)
from t;
```

The idea is to find the first row in the "next" 7 with a different value.  Then subtract that from the date in the current row.  The difference is what you want.

If all the rows have the same value, then the result would be `NULL`.  In general, you would want `7` in that case.  But at the end of the data, the effective window might be smaller, which is why this uses `count(*)`.

Comment: Thank you for the  help.
I actually solved it differently, not as elegant, but it works.
Hopefully this will help someone else as well :)